# Firebase - invalid token on device on iOS app

Tags: ios, firebase

I try to implement firebase in my iOS app.
I can't get pushes on my device.

For debug I tried to use curl request:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "Authorization: key=<my key here>" \
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
-d '{"notification": {"body": "Hello from curl via FCM!", "sound": "default"},
"priority": "high",
"to": "<my token here>"}'
```

If I try to use token that I get, launching app on real device I got following: error:"InvalidRegistration"

If I use token from my Android colleague (or even token I got from launch app on simulator device) I succeed and got something like message id in response.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Your payload seems to be incorrect, try following command in terminal and adjust it as per your requirement:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: key=<my key here>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  " data ": {
    "title": "Notification title",
    " body ": {
"name": "Body text",
}
  },
  "to": "<my token here>"
}' "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
```